# Convert number of hours to days and hours in SQL Server (NOT T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of hours which I need to display in the format of days and hours.

This number is derived from a `DATEDIFF` instruction.

For numbers less than 24, I wish to display only hours - ie, `21 hours`.

For larger numbers, I wish to display days and hours - ie, `3 days, 14 hours`

I do not need to display any smaller unit than hours, and values should be rounded down to the preceding hour, so 1 hour and 59 minutes will be 1 hour.

I cannot use a stored procedure - this must run as a single select statement.

I am aware that I can calculate the value by using modulo, so assuming 71 hours:

```
select concat((71 - (71 % 24)) / 24, ' days, ', 71 % 24, ' hours')
```

This however is somewhat messy, and as the statement must be a single select, I will have to calculate the `DATEDIFF` 3 times as below.

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        (DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartDate, EndDate) - 
        (DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartDate, EndDate) % 24)) / 24,
        ' days, ',
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartDate, EndDate) % 24,
        ' hours')
FROM RecordsTable
```

Is it possible to either format a number of hours as days and hours directly using an inbuilt SQL command, or failing that, `select (datediff(hour, StartDate, EndDate)` into a variable which I can reuse in the single select?

EDIT - As suggested, the solution was to use a CTE as follows:

```
WITH totalhours (htotal) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartDate, EndDate) AS htotal
    FROM 
        RecordsTable
)
SELECT 
    CONCAT ((htotal - (htotal % 24)) / 24,
            ' days, ',
            htotal % 24,
            ' hours')
FROM 
    RecordsTable;
```

Comment: You could use a CTE to get the date diff once. and then select from the CTE a single SQL statement as it's executed as one statement.  or use a subquery on recordstable to get the datediff once...

Comment: That did the trick - could you post as an answer and I'll accept please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE to generate your total once, and reference that total in your select against the CTE.  Or use a subquery to generate the total once and then select from the subquery to get the desired results.

The fundamental issue is you need to materialize the total once to be able to reference it; forcing the engine to materialize a value is generally done via a CTE or subquery.

Comment: This is the first time I've had to resolve anything along these lines on MSSQL. I have done similar work on Oracle, but I was not restricted in the same way and was able to use user created functions and stored procedures

Comment: TSQL has user functions and stored procedures as well that can be referenced in T-SQL.   You could have called a function here too; but I find this approach generally acceptable as well; though not as reuseable as the function would be.

Comment: The restriction is down to the project I'm working with. I would preferably just create a function which returns a formatted string from two dates, but I am not permitted to use one in this case.

Comment: Glad this we could help while operating in the restrictions of the project then.  Good Luck!

Comment: The help is much appreciated! As the DB is really quite large, we keep all functionality in .NET code so as to make maintenance easier. The project restriction has been a bit awkward at times, but the resitriction has been a help overall.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot with `datetime` objects and format strings or `datepart`. For example,

```
declare @n int = 105;
select format(dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(hour, @n, '1753-1-1')), 'd h');
-- 4 9
```

Taking the minimum `datetime` value (`1753-01-01`), adding the requisite number of hours, subtracting one day (because on the first day you want days = 0), and then formatting.

You could improve the formatting like this:

```
select format(dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(hour, @n, '1753-1-1')), 'd \da\y(\s), h \hour(\s)');
-- 4 day(s), 9 hour(s)
```

Of course this will only work up to 31 days, because then you'll be out of the month of January in 1753 and into February. If that's the case, revert to `datepart`. This is uglier, but will work for larger values

```
select 
   datepart(day, (dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(hour, @n, '1753-1-1')))),
   datepart(hour, (dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(hour, @n, '1753-1-1'))));
```

Comment: I've just had a play around with this, and sadly I'll have to stick with the `datepart` solution as many of the dates run well over one calendar month. However I derive the formatted date, I will still need to use the CTE as it must be referenced at multiple points in the rest of the query. The one on my example is truncated for brevity.